# dygraph php dynamically generate content from database

Tags: javascript, php, dygraphs

I am using Dygraph to display a graph. I have it working statically like this

```
<div id="graphdiv"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  g = new Dygraph(

    // containing div
    document.getElementById("graphdiv"),

    // CSV 
    "Date,High,Low\n" +
    "2015-05-07,75,40\n" +
    "2015-05-08,70,50\n" +
    "2015-05-09,80,60\n" +
"2015-05-10,60,40\n" +
 "2015-05-11,50,30\n" +
"2015-05-12,0,0\n"

  );

</script>
```

Now I want to use PHP to dynamically generate the content from a database. I have tried to do it like this. I create the associative array to get the information from the database and then add php bindings to

```
    <?php
//CREATE SQL STATEMENT
$sql_temperatures = "SELECT * FROM tbltemperatures";

//CONNECT TO MYSQL SERVER
require('inc-conndygraph.php');

//EXECUTE SQL STATEMENT
$rs_temperatures = mysqli_query($vconndygraph, $sql_temperatures);

//CREATE AN ASSOCIATIVE ARRAY
$rs_temperatures_rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs_temperatures);

?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

<!-- LINK TO THE DYGRAPH LIBRARY -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="dygraph-combined-dev.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<!-- CONTAINER HOLDING GRAPH -->
<div id="graphdiv"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  g = new Dygraph(

    // containing div
    document.getElementById("graphdiv"),

"Date,High,Low\n" +
    // CSV 
    <?php do { ?>

    "<?php echo json_encode($rs_temperatures_rows['tdate']); ?>,<?php echo json_encode($rs_temperatures_rows['thigh']); ?>,<?php echo json_encode($rs_temperatures_rows['tlow']); ?>\n"

    <?php } while ($rs_temperatures_rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs_temperatures)); ?>

  );
</script>
```

In theory, this should work in the function, however when I try to view it in any browser it will not display. Is there something stupid that I am missing?

I was thinking I may have concatenated incorrectly and it is displaying just not returning? I am not good at javascript and any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The do while loop inside the java script should look like this

```
"Date,High,Low\n" +

<?php do { ?>

    "<?php echo $rs_temperatures_rows['tdate'] . ',' . $rs_temperatures_rows['thigh'] . ',' . $rs_temperatures_rows['tlow']; ?>'\n' +

    <?php } while ($rs_temperatures_rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs_temperatures)); ?> '&nbsp;'
```